# Why do the eigenvalues minimize a variational problem?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, variational-principle, mathematics

Could anyone recommend a source where they prove or explain the following claim at an undergraduate level?

> "More generally, it follows immediately from the properties of Hermitian eigensystems that the eigenvalues minimize a variational problem."

Comment: [Min-max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) ? For unbounded self-adjoint operators, there might not be a rigorous proof at an undergraduate (physics) level. is [this](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7zo8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=%22More+generally,+it+follows+immediately+from+the+properties+of+Hermitian+eigensystems+that+the+eigenvalues+minimize+a+variational+problem.%22) the context?

Comment: Quote taken from where? Which page?